# how to upgrad tensorflow from 1.8 to the latest version

Tags: python, tensorflow

i was trying to install tensorflow using the following command:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

but because my internet connection is not strong enough and tensorflow needs a strong internet connection and i searched for other ways and i found a way on one of the answers here and it was by using the following method:

```
pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

and i used the command pip show to ensure that tensorflow indeed got downloaded and here is the results:

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.8.0
Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages
Requires: absl-py, astor, gast, grpcio, numpy, protobuf, six, tensorboard, termcolor, wheel
Required-by:
```

however, the tensorflow doesn't get run and give the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\imp.py", line 297, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>     
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ahmed\Downloads\cs50ai_week5\traffic\traffic\traffic.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\imp.py", line 297, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>     
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

i found someone suggest a solution that involves to download Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 but the setup failed and give me a message that says that another version already installed.
i'm using python 3.11 and working on vs code so, i tried to upgrade my tensorflow version because i thought it's probably a vary old verion using the following command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

but i got messages that says the requirement already satisfied.
how to solve that traceback and is it related to the version of my tensorflow?

Comment: You installed a version of TensorFlow for Mac, that is why it does not work at all.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy thanks. so, nothing related to my python nor tensorflow version after all.

Comment: Correct, Python 3.11 was only very recently released, it is likely that there is no packaged version of Tensorflow for it, I suggest that you downgrade to Python 3.10

Comment: After I downgrade it, It's getting downloading now. I don't trust my internet connection though.